# SQL: "NOT IN (SUBQUERY)" is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am facing the following conundrum in sqlite, and wonder if there's something I'm missing about the sqlite dialect.

Basically, when I ask for total unique values in one table I get one number.  When I ask for the subset of those values present in a second table I get smaller number.  But when I ask for the compliment of that subset I get 0.

Consider two tables, A and B, with different but overlapping populations of widgets denoted by a unique id we can call Widget_ID.

I am getting the following behavior:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET_ID)
FROM A
```

Output: 100

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET_ID)
FROM A
WHERE WIDGET_ID IN (SELECT WIDGET_ID FROM B)
```

Output: 75

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET_ID)
FROM A
WHERE WIDGET_ID NOT IN (SELECT WIDGET_ID FROM B)
```

Output: 0

Shouldn't this be impossible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The normal reason for problems with `not in` is the presence of `NULL` values.  `NOT IN` always fails when the list has `NULL` because `NULL` comparisons cannot be true.

You can fix this by filtering them outer:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET_ID)
FROM A
WHERE WIDGET_ID NOT IN (SELECT WIDGET_ID FROM B WHERE WIDGET_ID IS NOT NULL);
```

I prefer to use `NOT EXISTS`, because it has the semantics that you expect:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET_ID)
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT WIDGET_ID FROM B WHERE B.WIDGET_ID = A.WIDGET_ID);
```

Comment: Dynamite. That fixes it.  Thanks very much, I guess that makes sense.  Is that true in all SQL dialects?

Comment: NULLs have [some incompatibilities](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html), but the handling of NULLs in IN is consistent in all DBs.

Comment: @user1893148 . . . Basically "yes".  The handling of NULLs is defined by the ANSI SQL standards.  There are some nuances, but in all databases a comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL` (equivalent to false), except for special comparisons such as `IS NULL`.